# Automatically created Storage account option in azure

Tags: rest, azure

If i want to make use of automatically created storage account option thru REST API { i.e..implicit storage account creation in case if there is no such thing inside selected region } how can i achieve this in REST API call , especially what will be the value for media link in that scenario.

Whether are there any provision to pass on value as "automatic" or something else, so that it will create a new implicit storage in case if it is not available ?

Also how to differentiate an implicit account from other storage other accounts in a region ???

Comment: Whether i am missing something here ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a work around { may be the only way }...in case if i didn't find any storage account starts with "portalvhd.." and description as "implicitly created storage account" , i am just creating a new storage account with this attributes "portalvhd..' as starting phrase and description as "impli...account". In this way , i am able to achieve the behavior similar to portal.

Crossed one barrier...Still expecting more from azure :-)